# how do I flock in perl

Tags: perl, flock

If I run the following script in parallel I could see few are waiting for acquiring lock but some are running in parallel. LOCK_EX is not working as expected. I don't understand what is missing here.

```
$|++;
my $lockHandle;
my $file='lock.txt';
#sysopen( $lockHandle, $file, O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
open($lockHandle, '>>', $file);
print "aquiring lock\n";
my $o = flock $lockHandle,LOCK_EX or die "Could not lock '$file' - $!";
print "Locked....$o\n";

## Only executes when the lock is acquired

my $count=5;
my $intex=0;
while ($index <= $count){
   print "executing\n";
   sleep 1;
   $index=$index+1;
}
END {
 flock $lockHandle, LOCK_UN;
 close $lockHandle;
 unlink $file;
 }
```

Comment: Are you using [strict](https://perldoc.pl/strict)? Are you using [Fcntl](https://perldoc.pl/Fcntl)?

Comment: With proper `use strict` (and fixing errors related to this) and `use Fcntl ':flock'` I cannot reproduce what you are reporting. My guess is that the problem is due to blindly using undefined `LOCK_*` which then basically are no-op's.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, Not no-ops. `LOCK_EX` becomes equivalent to `"LOCK_EX"`, which `flock` treats as `0`. The `flock` is effectively a noop, though (returning error EINVAL).

Answer (score 3):

For starters, ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`! It would have found your problem.

You forgot to import the constants `LOCK_EX` and `LOCK_UN`, which you can do using

```perl
use Fcntl qw( LOCK_EX LOCK_UN );
```

(`O_RDWR` and `O_CREAT` would similarly need to be imported from the same module, if you were to use them.)

You end up passing the string `LOCK_EX` or `LOCK_UN` instead of the values the constants with those names represent. This is why the program dies with `Invalid argument`.